# Why do I get an incorrect value when I use a function as a parameter of strcmp?

Tags: c, strcmp

```
char *FuncA()
{
    char str[50] = "ex";
    return str;
}

void FuncB()
{
    char *a = FuncA();
    char *b = FuncA();
    int i = strcmp(FuncA(), FuncA());  // 1
    int j = strcmp(a, b);  // 0
}
```

Hello, I'm a little confused about how `strcmp` works now.
`FuncA()` is simply a function that returns the string `"ex"`.
Once you save the `FuncA()` return value and use `strcmp`, you will get the correct answer, but if you use `FuncA()` as a parameter of `strcmp` right away, you will get the wrong answer.
Can you explain why this is?

Comment: `FuncA()` returns an invalid pointer, since `str` is local variable that is invalid **after** `FuncA()` returns. So you are passing invalid pointers to `strcmp`.

Comment: Your confusion isn't about how `strcmp` works. It is clearly documented and easily understood. Your confusion is about *object lifetime*, and the manifestations of undefined behavior when you fail to consider it. You're sending dangling pointer values to `strcmp`. It does not know, nor care, that the addresses you're sending are invalid, so *you must care instead*.

Answer (score 2):

*"Debugging is a great source of learning." -Probably a wise man*

##### Notes:

1. In your function `FuncA()` you are returning a local variable which will be destroyed once it gets out of the function scope. Hence, `FuncA()` will return an [invalid pointer](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/c25.htm) which will cause [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior)
2. Return heap-allocated variable or variable with `static` linkage
3. The return value of `FuncA()` should be `const char *`, instead of just `char *`.
4. Both the functions `FuncA()` and `FuncB()` should be declared with `static` linkage
5. In your function `FuncB()` both the variable `a` and `b` should be of type `const char *` as you aren't changing them later in your code.
6. If any of your functions take zero arguments, then write them like `type func(void) { }`

##### Final Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char* FuncA(void)
{
  static const char str[50] = "ex"; // static linkage
  return str;
}

void FuncB(void)
{
  const char* a = FuncA();
  const char* b = FuncA();
  int i = strcmp(FuncA(), FuncA()); // 0 
  int j = strcmp(a, b); // 0

  printf("%d\n%d\n", i, j);
}

int main(void)
{
  FuncB();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why number 4? *Both the functions `FuncA()` and `FuncB()` should be declared with `static` linkage*

Comment: You could simplify `FuncA` as `const char *FuncA(void) { return "ex"; }`

Comment: @chqrlie `const char *FuncA(void) { return "ex"; }` came to my mind but I thought that I should write related code for OP

Comment: @chqrlie Those function should be static so that they do not collide with same function defined in another `<name>.c` file when compiled.